# How to ignore -ls errors in find

Tags: permissions, find

I'm writing a `find` command to look for files or folders with broken permissions (files should be `rw`, directories `rwx`) and trying to `ls -l` (give or take) the results.

The following `find` command looks like it works, but the `ls` part is giving me trouble.

```
find . '(' -not -readable ')' -or \
       '(' -not -writable ')' -or \
       '(' '(' -not -executable ')' -and -type d ')'
```

Adding `-ls` or `-exec ls -l {} \;` to the end works until it gets to a directory it can't read.  That gives a `permission denied` error and bails out completely without finishing.  Running `ls -ld $(<that command>)` works, as far as I can tell, but it feels like I'm missing something simple in `find`.

As an aside, I'm not worried about POSIX compliance, so I'd rather use `-or` instead of `-o` and such for readability.

Comment: `-exec ls -ld {} +`?

Comment: weird `find . '(' -not -readable ')' -or \
       '(' -not -writable ')' -or \
       '(' '(' -not -executable ')' -and -type d ')' -exec ls -l {} \;` works for me... What version of find you have?

Comment: @Kevin, same result.  @Braiam, 4.4.2, Ubuntu.  Adding more test cases, it doesn't seem to bail entirely, but it does change the result (it ignores other files, for some reason) and it doesn't actually `ls -l` the unreadable folders.

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on.

Comment: Note that putting -ls at the end will do an implicit -and. Since -and binds more tightly than -or, only directories will be listed. You probably want to add one more set of parentheses around the three conditions that are ored together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you hit a directory that's not executable, `find` tries to go into it, but it can't because, well, it's not executable. You need to tell it not to try by using `-prune`.

And put that condition first, so it's not short-circuited.

```
find . '(' '(' -not -executable ')' -and -type d -and -prune ')' -or \
       '(' -not -readable ')' -or \
       '(' -not -writable ')'
```

Comment: In a blank directory, `mkdir dir && touch file && chmod 440 *`.  The `find` without `-ls` or `-exec` finds them both.  Adding either returns nothing, and `-prune` doesn't seem to do anything in this case.

Comment: Move the prune part to the beginning, it's passing the not writeable condition so it doesn't get to the prune.

Comment: That does indeed prevent the permission denied errors, so it's helpful, but adding `-ls` or `-exec` returns a different result (missing the directory).  I'm guessing that that's a different question altogether and this should be accepted?

Comment: Put an additional `-ls` before the `-prune`

Comment: That did it.  For clarification, the extra `-ls` or `-exec` had to go before or after the `-prune` because the `-prune` was short circuiting the rest of the command.